# Powershell script to disable bit locker protection

Tags: powershell-4.0

Am a new bie to Powershell and knew less comlets.
As per my requirement, I need to disable the bit locker protection no a drive.
I have a script to get the status of bit locker protection is On or Off.

```
$x = Get-WMIObject -Namespace "root/CIMV2/Security/MicrosoftVolumeEncryption" -query "SELECT * FROM Win32_EncryptableVolume WHERE DriveLetter='C:'";
$y = $x.GetProtectionStatus().ProtectionStatus
$y
```

Which displays the protection status as 0 or 1.

Please help me with script to disable the protection for bit locker drive.

Answer (score 2):

Use the disable-bitlocker command: 
    PS C:> Disable-BitLocker -MountPoint "D:" 
Or whatever drive you need to disable. Why do you need to do this in the first place? There is a difference between disable and recover.

Answer (score 0):

There are as Charles pointed out proper cmdlets for this these days, instead of using the old-school WMI objects.

Get a list of all available commandlets for bitlocker

Get-Command `*Bitlocker*`

To disable on one of the drives, use the cmdlet:

Disable-Bitlocker

If you're stuck with an older version of Powershell/Windows, you can go for the approach of writing the value to the WMI object.